# How to replicate a ViewGroup n times in another ViewGroup but with different values for Views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewgroup

I am working on an Android application in which I have to create a card with multiple `TextView` and `ImageView` inside it. But these views are replicated multiple times in the card with different images and text (The attached picture summarizes my expected result better). I want to assign different images and text values to these views programmatically.

One solution is to use any layout and populate it with these Views, but it has too much code repetition. Another way is to create a vertical `LinearLayout` for the `TextView`, `ImageView`, `TextView` combination, and use `<include>` inside my parent Card. But how can I access the child Views by ID using this method to manipulate them later programmatically. What is the standard way of designing such a layout with minimum repetition of code? I hope there is a better way out. Here is the code for my `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_whatever_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_whatever"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_whatever_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the result I expect to create.
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use the Include way, give the Includes an ID

```
<include
android:id="@+id/whatever1"
```

You can refer to the items by

```
whatever1.textview_whatever_1
```

etc.

Comment: Oh well, it worked like a charm! I don't know why this idea never came to my mind. Thanks.